# datatables.js doesn't reload only display

Tags: javascript, json, datatables

Javascript from this Metronic v5.05 theme.

I have a page where I have a datatable printed and it displays fine.

I have put the whole javascript code that I use for display the table
but it is important for me that the tables reloads new data, if there is any.

I think I know how I would build this without datables.js but the guy
that I am building this project for insists I have to use it so I have to.

I have this code to make it work on my page.

```
    //== Class definition
var Dashboard = function() {
//== Hændelser hentes
    var datatableIncidents = function() {
        if ($('#LOGMSGS').length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var datatable = $('.m_datatable').mDatatable({
 layout: {
        theme: 'default',
        class: 'm-datatable--brand',
        scroll: false,
        height: null,
        footer: false,
        header: true,
        height: 400,
        smoothScroll: {
            scrollbarShown: true
        },

        spinner: {
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0,
            type: 'loader',
            state: 'brand',
            message: true
        },

        icons: {
            sort: {asc: 'la la-arrow-up', desc: 'la la-arrow-down'},
            pagination: {
                next: 'la la-angle-right',
                prev: 'la la-angle-left',
                first: 'la la-angle-double-left',
                last: 'la la-angle-double-right',
                more: 'la la-ellipsis-h'
            },
            rowDetail: {expand: 'fa fa-caret-down', collapse: 'fa fa-caret-right'}
        }
    },

    sortable: false,

    pagination: true,

    search: {
      // search delay in milliseconds
      delay: 400,
      // input text for search
      input: $('#generalSearch'),
    },
            data: {
                type: 'remote',
                source: {
                    read: {
                        url: 'http://beredskabsweb.dk/Template/alert-log-json.php'
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                saveState: {
                    cookie: true,
                    webstorage: true
                },
            },

            layout: {
                theme: 'default',
                class: '',
                scroll: false,
                footer: false
            },

            sortable: true,

            filterable: true,

            pagination: true,

            columns: [
            {
                field: "alertMessageTime",
                title: "Tid",
                width: 100,
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return '<time>'+row.alertMessageTime+'</time>';
                },
            },
            {
                field: "alertMessageText",
                title: "Text",
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return row.alertMessageText;
                },
            },
            {
                field: "alertMessageAuthor",
                title: "Forfatter",
                 width: 240,
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return '<a href="member.php?id='+row.alertMessageAuthor+'">'+row.MemberUsername+'</a>';
                },
            },
            ]
        });
    }


    return {
        //== Init demos
        init: function() {

            // datatables
            datatableIncidents();
            setInterval( function () { datatableIncidents();},4000);
        }
    };
}();

//== Class initialization on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Dashboard.init();
    setInterval(Dashboard,2000);
});
```

As you see i have tried to put this code in the bottom so that it should reload, but it doesn't.

```
setInterval(Dashboard,2000)
```

Comment: Have you tried:  $('.m_datatable').DataTable().ajax.reload();  ?

Comment: it didn't work :(

Comment: $('.m_datatable').mDataTable().ajax.reload();  ?
Which version of DataTables are you using?
The forums there are very helpful:  https://datatables.net/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reload api by metronic. You can see the docs here

http://keenthemes.com/metronic/documentation.html#sec14-5

First, you should export your datatable variable from the class so you can use it for other use like add function to reload the table or etc. I added below line:

```
    return {
        datatable: function() {
            return datatable;
        }
    };
```

After that, you also should create function to reload the table by the variable we just export before and by using reload api by metronic.

```
    reload: function {
        demo().datatable().reload();
    }
```

**Complete code:**

```
    //== Class definition
var Dashboard = function() {
//== Hændelser hentes
    var datatableIncidents = function() {
        if ($('#LOGMSGS').length === 0) {
            return;
        }

        var datatable = $('.m_datatable').mDatatable({
 layout: {
        theme: 'default',
        class: 'm-datatable--brand',
        scroll: false,
        height: null,
        footer: false,
        header: true,
        height: 400,
        smoothScroll: {
            scrollbarShown: true
        },

        spinner: {
            overlayColor: '#000000',
            opacity: 0,
            type: 'loader',
            state: 'brand',
            message: true
        },

        icons: {
            sort: {asc: 'la la-arrow-up', desc: 'la la-arrow-down'},
            pagination: {
                next: 'la la-angle-right',
                prev: 'la la-angle-left',
                first: 'la la-angle-double-left',
                last: 'la la-angle-double-right',
                more: 'la la-ellipsis-h'
            },
            rowDetail: {expand: 'fa fa-caret-down', collapse: 'fa fa-caret-right'}
        }
    },

    sortable: false,

    pagination: true,

    search: {
      // search delay in milliseconds
      delay: 400,
      // input text for search
      input: $('#generalSearch'),
    },
            data: {
                type: 'remote',
                source: {
                    read: {
                        url: 'http://beredskabsweb.dk/Template/alert-log-json.php'
                    }
                },
                pageSize: 20,
                saveState: {
                    cookie: true,
                    webstorage: true
                },
            },

            layout: {
                theme: 'default',
                class: '',
                scroll: false,
                footer: false
            },

            sortable: true,

            filterable: true,

            pagination: true,

            columns: [
            {
                field: "alertMessageTime",
                title: "Tid",
                width: 100,
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return '<time>'+row.alertMessageTime+'</time>';
                },
            },
            {
                field: "alertMessageText",
                title: "Text",
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return row.alertMessageText;
                },
            },
            {
                field: "alertMessageAuthor",
                title: "Forfatter",
                 width: 240,
                filterable: true,
                template: function(row) {
                    return '<a href="member.php?id='+row.alertMessageAuthor+'">'+row.MemberUsername+'</a>';
                },
            },
            ]
        });

        return {
            datatable: function() {
                return datatable;
            }
        };

    }


    return {
        //== Init demos
        init: function() {

            // datatables
            datatableIncidents();
            setInterval( function () { datatableIncidents();},4000);
        },
        reload: function {
            demo().datatable().reload();
        }
    };
}();

//== Class initialization on page load
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    Dashboard.init();
    setInterval(Dashboard.reload(),2000);
});
```

Comment: The link is dead.